# Xcode Source Kit will not stop crashing with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, xcode6.1, sourcekit

I need to find a solution to the super awesome "Source Kit Crashing" error with Swift. I have read many stack overflow posts but it doesn't seem like anyone has a solution. If there is a single line of code causing the problem there is no way I will find it by fishing through 50 + source files. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Xcode is essentially as useful as notepad it has gotten so bad. Please someone have a solution :). Source Kit crashes every single time I type a letter in any file.

Included Frameworks:
Parse, 
Layer, 
Fabric, 
Various apple frameworks

Note: My app compiles and run completely fine

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You've probably tried all this, but just in case:

1. close Xcode
2. remove `'~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/'`
3. remove `'~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode'`
4. restart your computer (just in case).

This should bring you code completion back, but the problem will eventually return. Xcode 6.1.1 beta (or now 6.2 beta with WatchKit) should fix many of the SourceKit related problems.

Comment: Alright I havent tried clearing ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode' so I will give that a try. Thanks

Comment: this worked! Nothing else did!  You are my new best friend! :)

Comment: I often deleted the `DerivedData` directory but never heard of the item within the `Caches` folder. That seems to work. Thanks :)

Comment: Removing com.apple.dt.Xcode worked best for me. The Xcode 6.1.1 update also helped a little...

Comment: Sorry, did not work for me.  But I did not restart my computer.

Comment: Removing the folder and file above is only a very temporary fix. It starts crashing again moments later, and I'm on XCode 6.2

Comment: Just a side note which may or may not be relevant, but I often find it necessary to not just delete items but also empty them from the trashcan. Xcode has a nasty habit of being able to access certain items while they're actually in the trash which can cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: @Ivicamil You are my new friend as well. :D

Comment: @Ivicamil It worked for the first time but now it is not working and I am stuck at the issue again. :(

Answer (score 3):

Dec 2, 2014, Apple deployed an update Xcode 6.1.1 that addressed the common source kit issue! For anybody who is coming across this issue.

Comment: It was really annoying !!! I hope it really solves this issue

Comment: I didn't notice a single improvement with Xcode 6.1.1 GM or 6.1.1 Mac App Store release. I'd even say it is worse than it was in beta.

Comment: Agreed, it's even worse in my case. It's hard to write any code in Swift at this point, it's slowing down to a crawl and crashing constantly. Clearing derived data only acts as a very short term fix, soon enough it reverts back to these issues.

Comment: 6.1.1 made my activity monitor report SourceKitService at 150-300% cpu usage. Very annoying.

Comment: There is a known / public issue with larger swift projects, anywhere from 4-10 KLOC where it halts and catches fire.  Cocoapods 0.36-Beta.2 is almost barely ready to break things into smaller frameworks, if that is any help. (see issue #3092).  I am using it right now, FWIW.  And off topic but useful, you can get more symbols if you derive  from NSObject (non pure Swift code)

Comment: Have Xcode 6.2 still and still seeing these crashes...a lot.

Comment: 6.3 still has these issues,its sad that you not only pay 99$/year, buy an expensive device to what avail! Make me miss eclipse,simple elegant and works like a charm! Apple has no respect for developers it seems...

Comment: I had this issue today.  XCode 9.2 (9C40b) ... My macbook was crashing / rebooting as soon as XCode restarted.  Deleting DerivedData and Caches solved it. (SourceKit was the culprit in the crash report.)