# XCode 9 hangs stucks on storyboard of project created in older version

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode9

I have a project which was created in xcode 7. I ran it on xcode 8 and it perfectly ran however now when I shifted to xcode 9. and open storyboard it hangs forever and specifically it shows "Signing product on status" on the status bar or shows "building custom shells..."
Any fix so far for this ?

Comment: Fun fact: Its XCode 10 now, and it *still* isn't fixed. Storyboards crash on my 2011/16gb mac on XCode 10, on my 2018 iMac pro at the office, and this has been the case since around XCode 7 or 8. Every ios developer I know despairs over this. Its intolerable that apple hasn't fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

Bug Report Response > Duplicate.
9.01 has not made a difference.
Recommendations:
1. Buy faster Mac with more memory.  3.2 or higher 8GB or more.
2. Close all other Apps: Safari, iTunes, everything!
3. If you have large storyboards break up into 40-50 GUI's each.
4. Run Clean often after editing or switching Storyboards
5. Try not to have Simulator running while editing storyboards.
6. Get a second Mac to do other things while you're waiting for storyboards to open, update and close.
7. Convert Storyboard views to code.
8. Be Patient
9. Pray for Apple to do something about this!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I managed to apply **all** of the following solutions at once:

1. [Change all "Top Bar" and/or "Bottom Bar" to "Inferred"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135687/4850928) - hard to make this point when Xcode freezes on Storyboard, but after rebooting Xcode I usually had a few seconds in which I succeeded.
2. [Clear Xcode cache data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084789/4850928) - in my experience computer restart isn't required.
3. [Clearing my xcuserdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40342783/4850928)

I'm not sure if all the points are required, but I think it's faster to do them all than to try to find out where the real problem lies.